# Is the following constructed number always irrational?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Given $\ $  $ a, b, c \in \mathbb{N} $, $\ $ $ a,b,c > 1  $, $\ $ $ b > c $, $\ $ $b$ and $c$ coprime, $a$ and $c$ coprime, is $ a^{\frac{b}{c}} $ irrational?

Examples: $2^{\frac{4}{3}}$, $13^{\frac{25}{12}}$.

Comment: $2^{\frac{2}{1}}$

Comment: Sorry, a b c > 1

Comment: $8^{4/3} = 16 \;$

Comment: What is true is it's either irrational or an integer. We can prove this with the monic special case of the rational root theorem.

Comment: take for example any $a=q^2$, $c=2$, then $a^{\frac{b}{c}}=q^b$

Comment: Please stop editing to add more limitations: it makes your post a moving target.  And in my example, 8 and 3 are coprime.

Comment: Sorry, I found later I haven't explained everything

Comment: Note that if $\large\sqrt[c]{a} $ is an integer, then under your conditions, $a^{b/c}$ will be an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\in \Bbb N$ and for prime $p$ let $F_p(x)$ be the largest $n\in \{0\}\cup \Bbb N$ such that $p^n$ is a divisor of $x.$

$(\bullet)$ . If $a,c\in \Bbb N$ and if $c$ is a divisor of $F_p(a)$ for $every$ prime $p$ that divides $a$ then $a^{1/c}\in \Bbb N....\;$ I.e. then $a=(a')^c$ for some $a'\in \Bbb N.$

If $a,b,c,d,e\in \Bbb N$ with $\gcd (b,c)=1$ and if $a^{b/c}=d/e$ then $a^be^c=d^c.$

So for *any* prime $p$ that divides $a$ we have $bF_p(a)+cF_p(e)=F_p(a^be^c)=F_p(d^c)=cF_p(d).$

So $c$ is a divisor of $bF_p(a)$ because $bF_p(a)=c(F_p(d)-F_p(e)\,).$

Now $c|bF_p(a)\implies c|F_p(a)$ because $\gcd (b,c)=1.$ So by $(\bullet)$ we have $a=(a')^c$ for some $a'\in \Bbb N.$ Hence, $d/e=a^{b/c}=((a')^c)^{b/c}=(a')^c\in \Bbb N.$

So if $a,b,c\in \Bbb N$ and $\gcd(b,c)=1$ then either $a^{b/c}$ is an integer or $a^{b/c}$ is irrational.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, can it be proved that at least one between a^(b/c) and (a+1)^(b/c) is irrational?

Comment: Yes, if  $\gcd(b,c)=1$ and  $c>1.$ Because  $a$ and $a+1$ cannot both be $c$-th powers of members of $\Bbb N....$

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true always.
For example, $a=4, b=5, c=2$, then $a^\frac{b}{c} = 32$ which is rational.
However, if you cannot find any $x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x^c=a$, then $a^\frac{b}{c}$ is always irrational. In my example, $x$ was $2$.

Comment: Thanks! What if a and c are coprime?

Comment: Ok, then take $a=9, b=5, c=2$. I was about to add something to the answer to get closer to what you may have meant but your comment made me to reply first.